# Exclude form fields from POST request

Tags: php, post, foreach, conditional-statements

I have a simple foreach statement grabbing all the fields from a submitted form. The fields are then put into a table that is sent via email. There are 3 fields that I need submitted and validated, but not sent with the email. Here is my script generating the table:

```
foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {

    if($name !== "num1" || $name !== "num2" || $name !== "captcha") {

        $text .= "<tr><td>$name</td><td>";

        //if form field is array
        if(is_array($value)) {

            foreach($value as $symptom) {
                $text .= $symptom . ", ";
            }

        //else no array
        } else {
            $text .= $value;
        }

        $text .= "</td></tr>";
    } 
}
```

Basically all form field names are set as `$name` and all values are set as `$value`. I am trying to include all fields except the ones named `num1`, `num2`, & `captcha`.

I am not redoing the way this form is handled, I just need to exclude these 3 fields from the table but my conditional statement isn't doing what I had expected. How can I ensure these three fields won't be included in the email?

Comment: You want to make sure that it is not num1 AND not num2 AND not captcha, so change your if to: 
    if($name !== "num1" && $name !== "num2" && $name !== "captcha")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `if($name !== "num1" || $name !== "num2" || $name !== "captcha")`
to `if($name !== "num1" && $name !== "num2" && $name !== "captcha")`

Comment: Oh wow. What a blonde moment :) -- This worked perfectly. Thank you for catching my mistake. I will accept the answer when I am able.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `||` in your `if()` to `&&`. Your if() as written will ALWAYS succeed, because whatever value you're testing will always "not be" any of those values at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's `continue` will skip an interation of a loop, then you change to using `==` comparison operators... Try this:

```
if($name == "num1" || $name == "num2" || $name == "captcha")
    continue;
else {
    // rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use && instead of || in if statement.